# How can I populate data which is fetched from API into select option in Laravel using VueJS and axios?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios

I have tried every way to fetch my API data into a select list. However, I have failed. All the information comes successfully. But whenever I try to show them it doesn't work. Is there any problem in my code?

My routes/web.php file

```
<?php

Route::get('/','StatusController@index');
```

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StatusController extends Controller
{
//

public function index(){


    return view('status-main');
   }
  }
```

My VueJS file

```js
<template>
    <div class="container">

        <h2>Total Recovered: {{Recovered}}</h2>

        <select name="" id="" >
            <option value="">Choose</option>
            <option   v-for="(list,index) in countryList" :key="list.id"   :index="index">

                {{list}}
            </option>

        </select>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        name:'CoronaStatus',
        data: function () {
            return {

                Recovered: "Loading ...",
                countryList:[],
                // Country:''

            }
        },
        // mounted(){
        //
        //     this.globalStatus();
        // },

        methods:{
            globalStatus:function () {
                const options = {
                    headers:  {"x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
                    "x-rapidapi-key": "ad21211fe4mshba485cda44108adp1712e0jsn54ed45914a9a"}
                };
                axios
                    .get("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/countries", options)
                    .then(response=>response.json())
                    .then(response => {
                        // this.Recovered = response.data.Global.TotalRecovered;

                        this.countryList=response.data;

                        console.log(this.countryList);
                        // alert(this.countryList)
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));

            }

        },

        mounted(){

            this.globalStatus();
        },



    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I have successfully fetched data every time. However, I have managed to fail to populate the select list.

[image]

[image]

My VueJS file after updating:

```js
<template>
    <div class="container">


        <select name="country">
            <option disabled value="">Choose</option>
            <option v-for="country in countryList" :key="country" :value="country">
                {{ country }}
            </option>
        </select>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            Recovered: "Loading ...",
            countryList: []
        }),
        methods: {
            globalStatus () {
                const options = {
                    headers:  {
                        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "x-rapidapi-key": "ad21211fe4mshba485cda44108adp1712e0jsn54ed45914a9a"
                    }
                }
                axios.get('https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/countries', options).then(res => {
                    this.countryList = res.data.response
                    console.log(this.countryList);
                })
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.globalStatus()
        }

    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a small example of the country list data?

Comment: I suggest you have a good read of this section in the Vue guide ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select. In particular, the _"Dynamic options rendered with `v-for`"_ part

Comment: You are using Axios, not `fetch` so you don't need to use `response.json()`. You will most certainly have errors reported in your developer console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should be consulting the documentation of the API you're using or at least look at the data its returning.

The API responds with something like the following

```js
{
  "get": "countries",
  "parameters": [],
  "errors": [],
  "results": 217,
  "response": [
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    //...
  ]
}
```

so you'll want something like the following in your code

```js
axios.get('https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/countries', options).then(res => {
  this.countryList = res.data.response
})
```

and in your template

```html
<select name="country">
  <option disabled value="">Choose</option>
  <option v-for="country in countryList" :key="country" :value="country">
    {{ country }}
  </option>
</select>
```

---

If you're wanting to work with the selection in Vue, you'll also want to bind it using `v-model`, eg

```html
<select v-model="selectedCountry" name="country">
```

and in your `data`...

```js
data: () => ({
  Recovered: "Loading ...",
  countryList: [],
  selectedCountry: ''
})
```

jsFiddle demo here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/caqx2zmr/

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer. But still, it's not working. All the data is in the alert box but it doesn't populate my list. I really dont know what to do

Comment: Do you have any errors reported in your browser console?

Comment: No sir, No error. Nothing. My select box is just not populating. Every other thing is Okay

Comment: @Maheeb your screenshot shows the result of an `alert()` but there is no such code in your question or my answer so where does that come from?

Comment: Sir, your demo seems to work fine.
I have copied and pasted your code. But still, it's not working.
Is it a problem with Laravel???

Comment: In my console.log it's return data but after that, it is saying source map error

Comment: Please update the code in your question to show what you currently have

Comment: Sir, I have updated it... 
If you have no problem you can use any desk and check my code from my pc
Sorry, I actually don't know what to do.

Comment: @Maheeb I'm curious now, what did you have to change?

Comment: Sir, I slapped myself twice after founding the error.

 <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>

I added this code twice by mistake. I added it one before my </body> tag and one after </html> tag. That's why the view did not render properly. I wast stuck for 8 hours and tried all other methods.

By the way, Thank you so much sir, For kind soul like you, the world is still a place for living.